# Glide v4 and Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-glide

I have a ListView with a custom BaseAdapter and a search toolbar to filter the list, every time I tap on the toolbar or I put a filter (read: every time the list is refreshed) there is a flickering due to the images reloading... how can I avoid this?

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.flag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.place = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.place);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.name.setText(customList.get(position).name);
    holder.place.setText(customList.get(position).city + ", " +
            customList.get(position).region + ", " +
            customList.get(position).state);
    String url = context.getString(R.string.main_server) + "flags/" + customList.get(position).state.toLowerCase() + ".png";
    Glide.with(context).load(url).into(holder.flag);
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save images to cache that way they will not be fetched again and set again every time you apply filter. Below is the code for that

```
apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC))
```

Note: This is in glide 4.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the answer by myself, but I still don't know why it works... I will leave it if it is of some use to anyone:
changing the loading part into this

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).apply(new RequestOptions().fitCenter().override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)).into(holder.flag);
```

solved the problem.